# C# Regex replace for custom json path

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string like this:

```
Books[?(@.Author=='auth1 or auth2' or @.Author=='auth3 or auth4' or @.Author=='auth5 or auth6')].Revision
```

I need the output as below using Regex.Replace:

```
Books[?(@.Author=='auth1 or auth2' || @.Author=='auth3 or auth4' || @.Author=='auth5 or auth6')].Revision
```

I tried using `Regex.Replace(string, @"(?<filter>@\..*) or @", "${filter} || @")`. But the output comes as:

```
Books[?(@.Author=='auth1 or auth2' or @.Author=='auth3 or auth4' ||
 @.Author=='auth5 or auth6')].Revision
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should use positive lookahead assertion.

```
Regex.Replace(string, @" or(?=\s+@\.)", " ||");
```

or

```
Regex.Replace(string, @" or(?=\s+@\.Author==')", " ||");
```

`(?=...)` called positive lookahead which asserts that the match must be followed by

`\s+` one or more spaces

`@.` @ and a dot.